# Trying a custom marker in openlayers. Image not showing

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers, marker, imageurl

I'm trying to use custom markers in OpenLayers, but the thing is that when adding the icon to the marker, the image is not showing. This is the code i'm using:

```
var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('marker.png', size, offset); 
markerslayer.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(position,icon));
```

The image is a PNG located on the same folder than the html. I don't know why doesn't show.
If someone can help me I would be thankful.

Comment: Try the answer I have post in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455477/vector-tiles-on-top-of-raster-tiles-is-not-getting-displayed-in-openlayers/46538341#46538341